# Socket Programming Only works on the same system and not on different ones

Tags: c, sockets

I have one problem with Server/CLient Socket Programming model.  On the same system meaning the same computer,I have a server running on one program and the client running another program.  The Server/Client are talking thru address 0.0.0.0 and port 3000. The communication is fine.

However, when I have the Server program running one system and Client Program running on another system(two different computers and both of them are Wifi capable) Then Socket Programming model DO not work for my anymore.

Why is that?

```
   portno=30000;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;


    char *srvr_addr=NULL;
    srvr_addr="0.0.0.0";
    inet_addr(srvr_addr);

    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr =inet_addr(srvr_addr);

    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    listen(sockfd,5);

    while (1)
    {

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
```

client side

```
     int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];

    portno=3000;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);




     server = gethostbyname("0.0.0.0");

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

   serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //source, destination
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
          (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
          server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(30000);

   serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    int result;
    result=connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr));

    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));

    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
```

Comment: You have "kinda" given us the code for the server end. Does a firewall/router etc figure into the equation along with the client "code"

Comment: @Paul, if I use htonl(INADDR_ANY) on Server side, then what should I use on client side? right now I have server=gethostbyname("0.0.0.0");

Comment: @lilzz: See my answer, you can't use `0.0.0.0` on the client side regardless of what you use on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect your client to IP address `0.0.0.0` across a network, that'll only work on the same computer. You'll need to have your client connect to a real IP address that your server has. Setting your server up to listen on `"0.0.0.0"`, or alternatively, `htonl(INADDR_ANY)` tells it to listen on any available IP address, but this is not a routable address across a network, it'll just connect to `localhost` when you use it locally, which is why its working for you when they're both on the same computer, but doesn't work when they're on different computers. Run `ifconfig` to find a real IP address for the server computer, and have your client connect to that.

You should also be checking the return values of all those functions. Every one of them can fail, and the first step to finding issues is checking the return from all of them and finding out which one is going wrong, and what the reported error message is.

You're also using some pretty obsolete functions. `inet_addr()` should be replaced by `getaddrinfo()` - although in this particular case, you don't need it at all, and should use `htonl(INADDR_ANY)` instead - and `gethostbyname()` should be replaced by `getnameinfo()`.

Comment: real IP address?  I am doing peer to peer networking. I don't have a router involved therefore there shouldn't a real IP address involved?Two system which are Wifi capable should be able to talk to each other without a router involved. No router means no real IP address involved.

Comment: If there is no real IP address involved, then you just can't use TCP/IP sockets. You'd have to use a different communication protocol altogether.

Comment: @lilzz - Your code is using the IP stack (the give away is "AF_INET". Hence each machine on that network has a unique IP address. 0.0.0.0 is the loopback one. How do you send a letter to somebody - it needs either a physic postman or better still an ADDRES

Comment: well, I did a ipconfig getifaddr en1 for my mac's IPaddress. it says 10.0.0.2. is that a real IP address?  Currently my mac is online,I guess that 10.0.0.2 is given by the router.  And if I go to different place, My mac should have different one?

Comment: @lilzz: Yes, `10.0.0.2` is a private network, but real IP address. If both computers are given IP addresses by the same router, they should both be different, and they should be able to talk to each other. Run your server on the `10.0.0.2` computer, and run your client to the other one, having it connect to port 30000 on `10.0.0.2`. You don't actually need to know the IP address of the client, since nothing is trying to connect to it.

Comment: @Ed Heal, IP address is given by router right?   Different routers will give the computer different IP address right?

Comment: @lilzz: Wait, why are we talking about *different* routers? If you're using private network addresses, which you are, then both of your computers have to be on the *same* IP network for any of this to work, so you'll likely only have one router involved. Different routers may very well give the same IP addresses out, but if you're on a private network, this doesn't matter, since private networks can't talk to each other by definition, and therefore can't have any IP address conflicts. That's pretty much the whole point of them.

Comment: @Paul, if my computer moved and got IP address from different router, how can I second system, computer know that? Different router means I go to the StarBuck and connect online and then I have different IP address. right now at home I have 10.0.0.2 but at starbuck I might have 15.0.0.5.

Comment: Probably a good time to go back to the textbooks.  [W. Richard Stevens series](http://www.kohala.com/start/) are considered by many to be the bible on this topic.  The wikipedia [network socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) page also has some good jumping-off points.

Comment: @lilzz - Depends if you are using DHCP. You can statically define it

Comment: @lilzz: It can't. Just make sure that doesn't happen. If you go to Starbucks, then you just can't talk to a computer on your private network at home, unless you have some kind of port forwarding set up on your home router which has a real, public IP address. And if you go to Starbucks you certainly can't connect to another computer at home over peer-to-peer wifi.

Comment: Well, that's hassle of the need to have a real IP address. The Client do not know when the Server IP got changed.  Myabe using Broadcast way to bypass that.

Comment: @lilzz: Well, what's the alternative? If you don't have a real IP address, you can't connect over an IP network at all, whether the server gets changed or not. If you're not on an IP network at all, then trying to use sockets with an invalid IP address is never going to work.

Comment: @lilzz - Going back to the metaphor - If your company moved office and the client owes you money. Does he put the cheque into the post without an address and hope for the best before you send in the bailiffs.

Comment: @Paul, Ok that way won't work I guess.  Let's say Server has valid IP, how does a Client find out that's server it wants to connect. Let's say there are Server A and Server B. How does Client know Server A's IP and let's say Client does not know Server A's IP ahead of time.  Can Server A send a broadcast message, "hey, I am Server A and my IP address is yyyy" so that CLient can know about it.

Comment: @lilzz: It might help if you actually stated what problem you're trying to solve, because the requested solution just seems bad. If two computers want to talk to each other without knowing where they are in advance, the normal way to do it would be for both of them to talk to a third server and either exchange information, or just do everything via the third server. Think of an instant messaging service, for instance, where two clients connect to a central server and register themselves, and they can find each other through that.

Comment: @Paul, have you heard about the Self discovery like Bonjour network

Comment: @lilzz: Some kind of broadcasting may possibly be a feasible solution locally, but if you're going to be heading to some random Starbucks, you can't broadcast to every one of the billions of computers on the internet hoping that one of them is the one that wants to talk to you, particularly not if the one that wants to talk to you is at home on a private network. I think this has gone beyond a programming question and become a need to just learn how basic networking works.

Comment: @Paul I don't need to broadcast to every computer. All I want is I bring the two computers and if I bring to Starbuck. They can talk immediately through some self discovery service and I guess Socket won't be workable implementing solution for self discovery service.

Comment: @lilzz: Something like that may be possible, but honestly, if you have both computers right there with you, just run `ifconfig` on one of them and get the IP address, it'll be much easier.

Comment: @lilzz: Then do some research into discovery services. Either way, this is now way off-topic for a stackoverflow question. Just remember that if you can go into Starbucks and discover all the services on one of your computers, so can everyone else who goes into Starbucks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give the client a fighting chance and give the IP address of the server?

Besides - Do summat about the code:

i.e. stuff like

- inet_addr(srvr_addr); on its own
- not using INADDR_ANY
- defining a variable for a port number and not using it

....

Comment: Let's say Server has valid IP, how does a Client find out that's server it wants to connect.  Let's say there are Server A and Server B.    How does Client know Server A's IP and let's say Client does not know Server A's IP ahead of time.

Comment: @lilzz - Have you though about this a little. When you want to talk to somebody either you have a phone number, email address, postal address, grid reference, ... Get the idea. Logical thing in this context is that you know their IP address (maybe via DNS lookup - Internet equivalent of a phone book). Hence why not register the computers name with a phone book (AKA DNS).